# TMOUT not working if user opens files

Tags: session, ssh, timeout

I'm managing small HPC linux cluster.

To close SSH session if it's inactive for a while, I configured TMOUT in the /etc/profile.
It works fine if users are on terminal without any file handling.

But, it does not work if users are staying with file handling such as editing file with vi editor, or print results on the terminal using tail -f commmand.

Those file handling are staying long time exceeding TMOUT variable.

Please let me know how to close this kind of SSH session.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is simple: Its not suppose to work in those cases. `tail -f` something printed on `STDOUT` same in case of open files using vi.
You would not want TMOUT close your connection when you are monitoring a log file or editing a file.

If you are intended to kill such sessions as well then:

1) You can get idle time from  `w`

2) Filter all those `TTY` which come in your exceeding `idle time`

3) `lsof /dev/TTY_value | egrep '^bash or your default shell'| awk '{print $2}'`

4) kill pids you get in step 3

I hope this will help your cause. But it's risky.

Comment: Put another way, `TMOUT` only applies when a shell is awaiting input, which it is not doing when another program is running in the foreground.

Comment: @chepner you want me to change or expand the answer?

Comment: No, my comment is just to explain to the OP (which I didn't make clear) that `TMOUT` was not applicable to his problem.